# 'Return' outside of function

Tags: for-loop, error-handling, return, syntax-error, enumerate

```
def suspect_dict():
 dict = pd.read_csv("suspectdict.csv", squeeze=True)
 pattern = '|'.join(dict)
 result = np.where(news_df["headline"].str.contains(pattern, na=False),1, 0)

for index, value in enumerate(result):
  return {value}
```

I am trying to return 1 and 0 if words in "suspectdict" exists in "news_df".

Code works for

```
for index, value in enumerate(result):  
  print(f"{value}")
```

example of output:

```
0
1
0
1
1
```

When using return I got Syntax error: 'return' outside function

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, your `return` is outside a function. `Return` should be used within a scope of a function, in your case, on `suspect_dict()` function.

You could either just loop the result and print it, without returning anything, also, you don't need to use enumerate as you're not dealing with indexes:

```
def suspect_dict():
    dict = pd.read_csv("suspectdict.csv", squeeze=True)
    pattern = '|'.join(dict)
    result = np.where(news_df["headline"].str.contains(pattern, na=False),1, 0)

    for value in result:
        print(value)
```

But if you need to return the result, you could just use return result inside the function:

```
def suspect_dict():
    dict = pd.read_csv("suspectdict.csv", squeeze=True)
    pattern = '|'.join(dict)
    result = np.where(news_df["headline"].str.contains(pattern,na=False),1,0)
    return result
```

Note that `python` uses indentation to understand where a block of code begins and ends, so make sure that all codes that might belong to the function are well indented.